# Drawing a 3d object inside a 3d object using java opengl1.0 for android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I have a 3D cube created using  GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP.Is it possible to draw  points(using GL_POINTS) or a triangle (using GL_TRIANGLE) on/inside my 3D Cube?How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw something directly of the face of another object (by using the exact same vertex coordinates), you will need to use `glPolygonOffset` to prevent stitching. There is a chapter in the [Red Book](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html) that explains it.

If by inside you mean to draw something in the volume of the cube, than there is nothing stopping you. You just need to get the alpha values and blending right to actually see through the cube. Look for some generic tutorial on transparency in OpenGL.

But maybe I'm horribly mistaken and what you are looking for a textures.

If I understand you correctly you could just generate the appropriate texture with the points and apply it to the cube.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yea, I need to plot a set of (x,y,z) points on a 3d cube.The points could be anywhere(on the cube/ inside the volume of the cube considering the cube as a 3d surface). How could I get the apha values?  Could you please provide any examples,tutorials or links? Thanks again.

Comment: @MRSGT_GT I added a few links. You really should start with a basic tutorial on Modern OpenGL instead of going in head first.